# Connecting Docker Container running on bridge network to Localhost

Tags: java, docker, localstack

I am running localstack (AWS mock service) locally as a docker container. I have another application which tries to connect to it but is getting connection refused error both are java projects. The network I am trying to use is called serview so I run localstack with the following

```
docker run --net=serview -d -p 4566-4597:4566-4597 --name=localstack -it localstack/localstack:latest
```

Then I run my other application that wants too access it like this

```
docker run --net=serview  -it --name sample-publisher -p 1338:1338 --rm sample-publisher:latest
```

The error I am getting is this

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:4575 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Running with net=host will work fine but I want to run on the serview network is this possible?

Comment: use container name to access it from another container. For now you are using localhost.

Comment: This worked, put as an answer i wiill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When containers are connected to a common network you should use container names to connect to each other. Container name is a DNS name that will be resolved to container IP over common network.

Comment: Hey I have one more question maybe you could help with, if i use the container name instead of localhost but I remove  the --net=serview then i get the connection error, i have a situation where i would like containers that are in the serview and where no network specified to be able to run against my localstack

Comment: Sorry might of explained that wrong but I want something in my java code that will work whether the localstack is running on bridge network or if it is ran with no network specified

Comment: Such things are done through environment variables. You pick value from environment in your java code. When launching the container you pass this environment variable which will be picked (either localhost or other container name).

Comment: How come the container name won't work if i run the docker containers without network specified?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. When containers are not connected to the user defined network, they are connected to default beidge network. You could access each other by IP but not by name. When containers are connected to a user defined network (like in your example) they can communicate through raw IPs or container names which will be DNS names resolved to their IP. You can find more info in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/)